# Parsing xml in Android without xml declaration using SAX

Tags: java, android, xml

Here's the XML I'm trying to parse: http://realtime.catabus.com/InfoPoint/rest/routes/get/51

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            // Download the XML file
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            // Locate the Tag Name
            nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("VehicleLocation");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

During runtime, when it reaches this line: `DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();` I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"RouteId":51,"R...@1:1298 in java.io.InputStreamReader@850b9be)
```

It seems to have something to do with the encoding. My *guess* is that it's because the XML doesn't sepcify the encoding, but maybe not.

Is there a way to specify the encoding in the code (I can't change the XML itself)?

Thanks!

**EDIT: This seems to only happen when parsing the XML from the url. Storing the file locally seems to work fine.**

Comment: the line DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder() is executed *before* the document is accessed. Is this the real code?

Comment: @mjn, it is. Is there an issue with that? db needs to be initialized before db.parse can be called

Comment: I would remove the part `During runtime, when it reaches this line: DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();`

Comment: Does the error show if you read the XML from a local file (thus bypassing the HTTP network layer)?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to specify the encoding in the code (I can't change the
>   XML itself)?

You can call `InputSource.setEncoding()` to set the encoding.

I would suggest to take a look at [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) instead for parsing XML in Android.